# Beyond Compare SASS Support

Tags: sass, beyondcompare, beyondcompare4

Does anyone know of a way for Beyond Compare to support sass (.scss) files?
I see they have .css support listed on their page for [Additional File Formats](https://www.scootersoftware.com/download.php?zz=kb_moreformatsv4).

Currently using Beyond Compare 4 (v4.2.6) Standard Edition and comparing files as "JavaScript Source", and have yet to find a more *correct* way of doing things.

Thanks!

Comment: What do you mean by support? It's just a text file, so BC will compare it.

Comment: You can define your own file formats with a specific sass-format (and then you could provide it at the [Scooter-Forum](https://www.scootersoftware.com/vbulletin/forum.php) so other people may start with an already defined file format. If you need additional help, please refine your question or make  a new one (How to define a grammer to detect a specific type of comment....)